# Checkbox checked length in gridview using asp .net server side

Tags: asp.net

I am having one `gridview` and `check box` for each `row` of `gridview` and one `button` outside `gridview`.
If I click on `button` then it should check for atmost one checkbox should be checked, otherwise it will display a message and return from loop. 
But how to get the `checkbox` selected length in `gridview` in serverside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if there is a `checkbox` checked in the `gridview` you can do this in the `button`:

```
bool isChecked = theGridview.Rows
                .Cast<GridViewRow>()
                .Any(a => ((CheckBox)a.FindControl("yourCheckbox")).Checked);
```

Do not forget `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop trough the row of the `gridview` and look for the `checkbox` as follows

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in YourGridView.Rows)
{
   foreach(string cnt in controls){
     int value =  Convert.ToInt32(((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)r.FindControl(cnt)).Value);
     bool isChecked = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)r.FindControl(cnt)).Checked;
     //now you have id and checked/unchecked. use your query to save it to database
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Manipulate this according to you requirement.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in final.Rows)
{

     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
     if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
     {
          //Perform action 1
     }
  else
     {
         // perform action-2
     }
```